# PHP API stdClass value

Tags: php

I've being searching arround, but i couldn't find anything yet

Im using and API in my php code similar to this:

```
Array(
    [randomName] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 412
        [key] => NameKey
        [name] => Name
        [title] => some title
    )
)
```

I need some help with this, how can I get the [key], since the [randomName] it's a random name that the developer used?

This has 124 values like this:

```
Array(
    [randomName] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 412
        [key] => NameKey1
        [name] => Name 1
        [title] => some title
    )
    [something] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 412
        [key] => NameKey2
        [name] => Name 2
        [title] => some title
    )
    [othename] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 412
        [key] => NameKey3
        [name] => Name 3
        [title] => some title
    )
    [otherthing] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 412
        [key] => NameKey4
        [name] => Name 4
        [title] => some title
    )
    [somethingelse] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 412
        [key] => NameKey5
        [name] => Name 5
        [title] => some title
    )
)
```

I need to get all the [key] to an array but I don't know how I'm going to get inside the [randomName].

Any one knows?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Can't you use `foreach($array as $k=>$v)` and then scan `$v->key` ?

Comment: Your outer structure is just an array (of objects), so this really isn't any more difficult than `foreach ($outer_array as $obj) { echo $obj->key; }`

Comment: Of course, there are various methods to collect all the `key`s into an array. Do you want to maintain their associations with their `randomName` array key, or just produce a simple array of `key` values?

Comment: An array of key values, this "key"->value, is what i need in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing the problem, but,

Random name is the key in the array, and key in the object is a property so:

```
$newList = array();
foreach ($values as $ramdomName => $object) {
   $newList[] = $object->key;
}
```

Comment: I was just messing up everything, didn't seem so easy xD
Thank you

Comment: I have that every day before the first coffee. you're welcome